# How to save custom meta only for review data to see only in "Preview Changes", not the actual post in the front end

Tags: wordpress, metadata, revision

I am trying to add custom meta and see at "Preview Changes". I can see the changes but also changes apply to the actual post at Front end. I want the changes will update to the actual post when it Publish or Update not at "Preview Changes" click. Please help.
I have followed this plugin.

function my_plugin_save_post( $post_id, $post ) {

```
if ( $parent_id = wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {

    $parent  = get_post( $parent_id );
    $my_meta = get_post_meta( $parent->ID, 'my_meta', true );

    if ( false !== $my_meta )
          add_metadata( 'post', $post_id, 'my_meta', $my_meta );
}
```

} add_action( 'save_post', 'my_plugin_save_post' );

Answer (score 0):

The following code will prevent your meta data from saving on preview but **You won't be able to preview published posts with your metadata.**  Honestly I'm trying to figure out this situation myself :/

```
<?php // In your save metabox data function, near the top...
if (isset( $_POST['wp-preview'] ) && 'dopreview' == $_POST['wp-preview'] ) {
  if(get_post_status($post_id) == 'publish'){
    return; // This way we can still preview draft / scheduled posts
  }
}
```

Honestly, I'd use this code and set your post briefly to `draft` or `private` while editing / previewing and publish them as normal when you're done.